# VSCode extension: How to programmatically show view container in panel

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing a VSCode extension which has a view container with a `WebviewView` added to it.

```json
"contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "showView",
        "title": "Show view"
      }
    ],
    "viewsContainers": {
      "panel": [
        {
          "id": "mycontainer",
          "title": "My Container",
          "icon": "media/app.svg"
        }
      ]
    },
    "views": {
      "mycontainer": [
        {
          "type": "webview",
          "id": "myview",
          "name": "MyView"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

In `showView` command implementation. I want to programmatically make the view `myview` to display in VSCode UI. How to do that?

Comment: if there is no public API to show a ViewContainer and/or put focus on a view in the container you might file an feature request at github, also nice to find out in which container/panel a view is currently

Answer (score 11):

You can focus on a view in the sidebar by using the view's `id` and executing the `focus` command:

```ts
vscode.commands.executeCommand("myview.focus")
```

Comment: This doesnt work for a panel webview before its opened manually by the user

Comment: Work for me on VS Code 1.64.1. The panel is opened automatically, even if it was closed before.

Answer (score 4):

VSCode exposes a `focus` command on every view registered.

Your example view has ID `myview` so you want to call the `myview.focus` command.

You can verify this by opening `File->Prefs->Keyboard Shortcuts` and searching for `myview`.

To test the command, try adding the following in your extension activate function. It will create a clickable button on the bottom statusbar that will focus your sidebar view.

```ts
activate = function (workspace) {
    const statusBarItem = vscode.window.createStatusBarItem(vscode.StatusBarAlignment.Right, 10);
    statusBarItem.command = 'myview.focus';
    statusBarItem.text = 'MYVIEW';
    statusBarItem.show();
    workspace.subscriptions.push(statusBarItem);
}
```