# Is it possible to programmatically select an item from activity bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a VSCode extension that will be show as a ViewContainer with an icon on the Activity Bar. I would like to startup VSCode and the default selected item from the Activity Bar should be may custom extension.

Is there any VSCode API which I can tell it that this ViewContainer is the default one?

Another approach can be a way to programmatically select this ViewContainer from the activity bar after my extension is activated (so its icon will be shown as selected). Is it possible too? This approach is kind of the way the "Find All References" option works: any time we click it, it is shown selected at the activity bar.

Appreciate if anyone could help me on this!

Comment: I have not tried it but this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/67824902/9938317

Comment: Nice @rioV8 ! The focus command really solved my issue! Thanks a lot! Please, put your comment as answer so I can accept it!

Comment: we can mark this as a duplicate question and give the credit to DAC

Comment: I closed as a duplicate and upvoted the answer there.